# How can I implement a generic min?

Tags: c++, templates

When I write

```
T min(T& a,T& b)
{return a<b?a:b;}
```

and call `min(3,4)`, it will yield a error.

How can I implement a generic min?

Comment: By using [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)? Or do you mean [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)?

Comment: By the way, that's a `min`, not a `max`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because non-`const` lvalue references (`T&`) cannot bind to rvalues (`3` and `4` are rvalues, which intuitively means that they do not have an object identity).

Try using lvalue references to `const` instead, which *can* bind to rvalues (after all, the `min()` function is not supposed to alter the state of its arguments).

Besides, do not forget the `template<typename T>` part if you are writing a function *template*:

```
template<typename T> // <== Don't forget this, if you are writing a template
T min(T const& a, T const& b)
//      ^^^^^       ^^^^^
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

For instance, consider this small program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> // <== Don't forget this, if you are writing a template
T min(T const& a, T const& b)
//      ^^^^^       ^^^^^
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    int y = 1729;

    std::cout << min(x, y) << std::endl; // Passing lvalues, that would be OK also
                                         // with your original code.

    std::cout << min(42, 1729) << std::endl; // Passing rvalues, this would not be OK
                                             // with your original code (non-const
                                             // lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues)
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24342).

---

**UPDATE:**

The above solution only allows passing values *of the same type* to `min()`, otherwise the compiler won't be able to perform type deduction (if the first and second argument have different types, what should `T` be?):

```
min(3.14, 42); // Huh? What is `T` here, `double` or `int`?
```

To force the compiler to use a specific type for `T`, you can specify the template argument explicitly:

```
min<double>(3.14, 42);
```

However, this is not a very elegant choice (the user has to type the correct template argument manually every time). Rather, you could let your function template accept *two* template type parameters instead of one:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::common_type<T, U>::type min(T const& a, U const& b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

And use the [`std::common_type<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) type trait (available since C++11) to figure out the right type to be used as the return type.

Once again, here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24345).

Comment: @user2248425: What does the error message say? See the linked live example, it seems to work there. Are you sure you copied everything correctly, including the `template<typename T>` part?

Comment: @user2248425: See the udpated answer for an explanation of how to make `min(3.14, 42)` work.

Comment: Your version is not Standard-proof: according to 25.4.7/3 it should "return the ﬁrst argument when the arguments are equivalent." That means a definition like `return (b < a)? b : a;`

Comment: @rhalbersma: I accept your objection, but I don't like calling it STL ;)

Comment: fair enough (fixed), note that the analogous `std::max` is not stable by oversight of Stepanov himself when he proposed the STL!

Comment: see page 62/63 of [Notes on Programming](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the template header

```
template<typename T>
T const& min(T const & a, T const & b)
{
   return a<b?a:b;
}
```

You can do that for max in similar way:

```
template<typename T>
T const& max (T const &a,  T const& b)
{
  return a<b? b:a;
}
```

You have to make sure that the type T supports < operator

Comment: error!i read a book says that if i call min(3,3.1) the complier will get confused.but how can I write?

Comment: @user2248425: I explain this in my answer

Comment: @user2248425 You have to know that when template arguments are deducted, no automatic conversion is done, if you pass int, double into it, compiler get confused, so error. you can either explicitly instantiate it or do cast when passing.